# Queuing email in Laravel 4 with sync driver

Tags: php, email, laravel-4, queue

I just want to queue an email when an user registers. So I do this when the user posts the registration form:

```
Mail::queue('emails.activate', $data, function($message) use ($user)
{
  $message->from('no-reply@mysite.com', 'Mysite.com');
  $message->to($user->email, $user->username)->subject('Welcome');
});
```

The queue listener is running (php artisan queue:listen) and a supervisor process make sure it will restart if stopped.

It works, the user get the email but the HTTP response when registering is very slow, exactly as I would expect it to be if I was trying to directly send the email. If I comment all the queuing code above, the HTTP response time is just fine.

I use the sync driver in queue.app:

```
'default' => 'sync',
'connections' => array(

    'sync' => array(
        'driver' => 'sync',
    ),
    etc...
```

At last, I run my own private server (Ubuntu) with postfix. Can someone help me figure out why the response is so slow while I'm queuing the email?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sync driver runs its queued jobs just before Laravel ends its execution. That is why it is called the sync driver, you will need to change it to achieve desired functionality.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I just assumed it was kind of the "email spooling" functionality of Symfony2...

Comment: The sync driver is simpler than that, you'll have to use a different driver :)

Comment: You can use the `pretend` feature from the mail configuration file while developing if you want.  Other than that, you will need to change the queue driver to have a proper queue.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna have a look on Beanstalkd. Thanks!

Comment: So is it working on background or it will be synchronous as normal script?